# Generate XML Schema for Domain Classes in Grails

Tags: grails, asp-classic, xsd, dns, grails-domain-class

Could you please suggest a service or plugin which generate the corresponding XML Schema for a given Domaing Class or for all Domain Classes of Grails project.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin does exactly what you're asking.

http://grails.org/plugin/domain-schemagen

Answer (score 0):

You just need to type the following command shell from your project root directory:

```
> grails schema-export
```

See [schema-export](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/schema-export.html) documentation for further details

It will generate a DDL file.

From there, you need to convert it into XML (if you really want XML).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a database migration to control all the schema generation and to manage future changes. We use [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org), it's very easy to use and flexible and there is already a [Grails plug in](http://www.grails.org/plugin/liquibase) for it. All the changes in Liquibase are managed in XML format.

Also, if I am not mistaken database migrations are going to be integrated in Grails core for version 1.4 so you will be able to use schema migrations without having to install any plug in and I think with this you would be able to manage your changes using DSL as well.